# Configure the .bzr directory path in a bazaar repository

Tags: bazaar

I want to create a bazaar repository and have the **.bzr** directory not alongside the versioned files.
I'm searching for an option like "--git-dir" in git, or a way to achieve the same thing. Evenctually I'd accept an hack too.

A solution using bzrlib is feasible

Example current structure

```
project/.bzr
project/foo_versioned_file
project/bar_versioned_file
```

Wannabe structure

```
project/foo_versioned_file
project/bar_versioned_file
/unrelated_path/.bzr
```

Comment: Have you considered using lightweight checkout instead?

Comment: no, I didn't know about them, I must learn if they can help me solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing like --git-dir in bzr, but if you only need avoid having the full history along your working tree, then it's worth to consider using lightweight checkouts. Lightweight checkouts allow you to use only small number of files in .bzr/ directory (but you have to have it anyway) and the real branch with its repository and its history can be kept outside the working tree. So:

```
bzr branch bzr+ssh://HOST/REPO/BRANCH /unrelated_path
bzr checkout --lightweight /unrelated_path project
```

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but I'll have an user working on the versioned dir and I need to ensure he doesn't touch the .bzr dir (the user doesn't know a thing about versioning control, it's all part of a master plan)

Comment: @Riccardo Galli: see also bzr-upload plugin if you only need update the files in directory from your master branch.

Comment: @Riccardo Galli if you're on Linux you may try to set appropriate filesystem permissions and block your user to access .bzr directory content.

Comment: I'm writing a cross platfom application, and I'll eventually end up using something like that after I verified that it's impossible also via the bzrlib api